# How to avoid a ParamGuard not satisfied when fitting a SVM model using Rust's Linfa?

Tags: rust, svm

I just start testing [`linfa`](https://docs.rs/linfa) and I am getting an error that makes little sense to me at the moment.

I have my `data` which is a `Vec<Vec<f64>>`. This data has its `labels`, which is a `Vec<bool>`.

From there I tried something like that:

```rust
let input = Array2::from_shape_vec((data.len(), 384), data)?;
let targets = ArrayView1::from(&labels);
let dataset = Dataset::new(input.to_owned(), targets.to_owned());
let model = Svm::params()  // ignoring train/test by now
    .pos_neg_weights(50000., 5000.) // copied form their GitHub example
    .gaussian_kernel(80.) // idem
    .fit(&dataset);
```

This makes the compiler complain that `ParamGuard` is not satisfied for `SvmValidParams<{float}, _>`:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `SvmValidParams<{float}, _>: ParamGuard` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:67:10
   |
67 |         .fit(&dataset)?;
   |          ^^^ the trait `ParamGuard` is not implemented for `SvmValidParams<{float}, _>`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `ParamGuard`:
             PlattParams<F, O>
             SvmParams<F, L>
   = note: required for `SvmValidParams<{float}, _>` to implement `Fit<ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<Vec<f64>>, Dim<[usize; 2]>>, ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<bool>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>, _>`
   = note: 1 redundant requirement hidden
   = note: required for `SvmParams<{float}, _>` to implement `Fit<ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<Vec<f64>>, Dim<[usize; 2]>>, ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<bool>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>, _>`
```

I have tried `targets` as `Vec<usize>` too, no success.

I have the impression my input data type to the dataset is messed up, but I cannot understand how/why. Any ideas?

Library versions:

```
linfa = "0.6.1"
linfa-svm = "0.6.1"
ndarray = "0.15.6"
sprs = "=0.11.0"
```

Comment: Judging purely by [the docs](https://rust-ml.github.io/linfa/rustdocs/linfa_svm/hyperparams/struct.SvmValidParams.html) and the fact that the type resolves to `SvmValidParams<{float}, _>` (notice the second type parameter being unresolved), might there be a possibility that you mistake `SvmParams::fit` to `SvmValidParams::fit`? Try specifying the desired return type as the docs say.

Comment: `Array2::from_shape_vec` expects a flat vector, i.e. it expects a `Vec<float>`, not a `Vec<Vec<float>>`: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=753346cdc1994836ad0aec62bc72cc1a).